# Display Map in Form

Tags: c#

I am displaying google map with a WebBrowser and it's not what I want. I want to display ONLY the map and maybe some markers on it... not the browser version in my form.. 
Here is what I did:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string street = textBox1.Text;
    string city = textBox2.Text;
    string state = textBox3.Text;

    try
    {
        StringBuilder queryaddress = new StringBuilder();
        queryaddress.Append("https://maps.google.com/maps?q=");

        if (street != string.Empty)
        {
            queryaddress.Append(street + ",+");
        }
        if (city != string.Empty)
        {
            queryaddress.Append(city + ",+");
        }
        if (state != string.Empty)
        {
            queryaddress.Append(state + ",+");
        }

        webBrowser1.Navigate(queryaddress.ToString());
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message.ToString(), "Error");
    }
}
```

Also... how can I place markers even on this version of the map?

Comment: first of all watch questions with this tag 'google-maps' and also this link may help you http://alvarestech.com/temp/routeconverter/RouteConverter/navigation-formats/src/main/doc/googlemaps/Google_Map_Parameters.htm

Comment: Does it have to be google maps? Otherwise you could add the WPF map control. No need for browser and javascript etc. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx and  https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rbrundritt/2013/11/08/using-bing-maps-in-winforms/

Comment: @PeterBons I'll have to search for locations later and add markers... also I dont know how to add this control

Comment: But everything is in the docs, start here https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh830431.aspx. Or search for more info, like https://visualstudiomagazine.com/Articles/2012/04/01/Map-Your-Apps.aspx. And the second link in my first comment tells how to add this control